# Really frustrating Python/Numpy error. "could not broadcast input array from shape (6) into shape (1)"

Tags: python, numpy

ValueError

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-129-810db8fa03c3> in <module>()
     20     # TODO:<your code here>
     21 
---> 22     w=np.subtract(w,(compute_grad(X_expanded[ind, :], y, w)))
     23 
     24 
shape = (6, 1)
weight_gradients = np.empty(shape,)

for k in range(len(w)):
    sum_gradient = 0
    #print(sum_gradient)
    for i in range (len(X)):
        linear_model_output=X[i,0]*w[0]+X[i,1]*w[1]+X[i,2]*w[2]+X[i,3]*w[3]+X[i,4]*w[4]+X[i,5]*w[5]
        exp_lmo = np.exp(linear_model_output)
        y_i=y[i]
        add_to_grad = -X[i][k]*1*(y_i*exp_lmo-exp_lmo+y_i)/(exp_lmo+1) 
        sum_gradient = sum_gradient + add_to_grad

    sum_gradient = sum_gradient/len(y)

    weight_gradients[k] = sum_gradient  ############ERROR LINE
```

at `weight_gradients[k] = sum_gradient` I receive the error.

My guess is that its due to a frustratingly stupid lack of knowledge of the language.  Unfortunately, I have previously used code exactly like this in my program and it hasn't thrown up an error, really just making me rather confused.

Comment: Have you looked at `sum_gradient`?  The error indicates that it is a 6 element array (or list).  Is that what you intend?  You are trying to put this in a single element slot of a 1d array.

Comment: I don't see how it could be one.  I declared it as a variable equal to 0, then only updated it with values that *should* be scalars, or values of a matrix element.

Comment: I'm asking about real values, not what you think should be happening.  When we debug code, especially in Python, we look at actually values.  We don't just replay the code in our head.  Print values, and if they don't make sense, print earlier ones until you find the first step that does something unexpected.

Comment: If you gave us a [mcve] we could run your code, and print some debugging values.  But you haven't given enough code or values to copy-n-paste and run.